# Pandas: replace substring in string

Tags: python, pandas, replace, dataframe, substring

I want to replace substring `icashier.alipay.com` in column in `df`

```
url
icashier.alipay.com/catalog/2758186/detail.aspx
icashier.alipay.com/catalog/2758186/detail.aspx
icashier.alipay.com/catalog/2758186/detail.aspx
vk.com
```

to `aliexpress.com`.

Desire output

```
aliexpress.com/catalog/2758186/detail.aspx
aliexpress.com/catalog/2758186/detail.aspx
aliexpress.com/catalog/2758186/detail.aspx
vk.com
```

I try `df['url'].replace('icashier.alipay.com', 'aliexpress.com', 'inplace=True')` but it return `empty dataframe`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) with `dict` for replacing and `regex=True`:

```
df['url'] = df['url'].replace({'icashier.alipay.com': 'aliexpress.com'}, regex=True)
print (df)
                                          url
0  aliexpress.com/catalog/2758186/detail.aspx
1  aliexpress.com/catalog/2758186/detail.aspx
2  aliexpress.com/catalog/2758186/detail.aspx
3                                      vk.com
```

Comment: This appears only to work for a column, not for a dataframe. When I try this on a dataframe it no longer finds substrings.

Answer (score 29):

use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) to replace a substring, `replace` looks for exact matches unless you pass a regex pattern and param `regex=True`:

```
In [25]:
df['url'] = df['url'].str.replace('icashier.alipay.com', 'aliexpress.com')
df['url']

Out[25]:
0    aliexpress.com/catalog/2758186/detail.aspx
1    aliexpress.com/catalog/2758186/detail.aspx
2    aliexpress.com/catalog/2758186/detail.aspx
3                                        vk.com
Name: url, dtype: object
```

Comment: The .str fixed it for me with this one. if you commit .str then it does not replace substring in string

Answer (score 2):

In case someone (like me) needs to replace **substring** in whole DataFrame:

```
df = df.apply(lambda col: col.str.replace('icash...', 'aliex...'))
```

or just in defined columns (and all others remain unchanged):

```
cols = ['a', 'c'] # list of all columns with value to replace
df = df.apply(lambda col: col.str.replace('icash...', 'aliex...') if col.name in cols else col)
```

Comment: For the entire data frame, you can also use `df.replace('icash...', 'aliex...', regex=True)`