# Replace specific substring in match python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, replace

I was to use regex to replace a substring of a matched string in a df series.
I have looked through the documentation (e.g. [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38565849/pandas-replace-substring-in-string) ) and I have found a solution that is able to capture the specific type of string that I want to match. However, during the replace, it does not replace the substring.

I have cases such as

```
data
initthe problem
nationthe airline
radicthe groups
professionthe experience
the cat in the hat
```

In this particular case, I am interested in substituting "the" with "al" in those cases where "the" is not a standalone string (i.e. preceeded and followed by whitespaces).

I have tried the following solution:

```
patt = re.compile(r'(?:[a-z])(the)')
df['data'].str.replace(patt, r'al')
```

However, it also replaces the non-whitespace character preceding the "the".

Any suggestions on how what I can do to just repalce those specific cases of a substring?

Comment: But `inithe` will turn into `inial`, I guess you need `initial`? Even if you fix it to `df['data'].str.replace(r'(?<=[a-z])the', r'al')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a lookbehind, which checks (asserts) for a character before `the`, but does not actually consume anything:

```
input = "data\ninitthe problem\nnationthe airline\nradicthe groups\nprofessionthe experience\nthe cat in the hat"

output = re.sub(r'(?<=[a-z])the', 'al', input)
print(output)

data
inital problem
national airline
radical groups
professional experience
the cat in the hat
```

### Demo

Comment: Though it is what OP tries to use, the result will probably not be "final" since `inithe` will turn into `inial`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I interpret this as bad sample data, not a bad regex solution.

Comment: Well, another dupe anyway.

Comment: Yes, sorry. There was an error in the simple data I updated it.