# How do i replace all instances of a dash (-) with the number zero (0) in the middle of a string in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, replace

I have a column that has 5 numbers then a dash then another 5 numbers for example 44004-23323. I would like to remove that dash in the middle. I would like the output to be something like this 44004023323
I have tried this code below but its not working.

```py
df['Lane'] = df['Lane'].apply(lambda x: "0" if x == "-" else x)
```

Comment: Can you post `df['Lane']` contents?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about .str.replace()?

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html

[Pandas: replace substring in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38565849/pandas-replace-substring-in-string)

```py
# see documentation for other parameters, such as regex and case
df['Lane'] = df['Lane'].str.replace('-', '0')
```

Comment: @JumaHamdan Is the dash always in the middle? This solution will replace all dashes anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
df['Lane'] = df['Lane'].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace('-','0'))
```