# Pandas Create a new column C with values of column A but without the hyphens

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, data-wrangling

I have

| Alpha. | Beta. |
| --- | --- |
| ZUP9W----GU3 | 128374 |
| UI09--12D | 1219313 |

I NEED:

| Alpha. | Beta. | Gamma |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ZUP9W----GU3 | 128374 | ZUP9WGU3 |
| UI09--12D | 1219313 | UI0912D |

Basically a new column Gamma with values of column A without the hypens.

Thank you=)

Comment: [str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) -> `df['Gamma'] = df['Alpha.'].str.replace('-', '')`

Comment: Very similar to [How do i replace all instances of a dash (-) with the number zero (0) in the middle of a string in pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58562017/15497888) and an extensive list of methods is here [Remove unwanted parts from strings in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13682044/15497888)