# How to replace the * character in a Data Frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to automate the transformation of a source file that contains the * character in one of the columns as opposed to a null value (why they did this I have no idea).

I have data like, I want to remove the * and have null's in COL_2

```
COL_1 | COL_2

XYZ   | *

XYZ   | 123
```

Reading data such as

```
df = pd.read_csv(my_file, names=["COL_1"],["COL_2"], header=0)
```

doing replace

```
df['COL_2'] = df.['COL_2'].replace('*', '', regex=True)
```

I get error like

```
line XXX, in <module> df['COL_2'] = df.['COL_2'].replace('*', '', regex=True)

line XXX, in replace return super().replace(
```

Thanks and sorry if this is asked somewhere I had trouble finding it.

edit: The issue was passing Regex argument which I had been doing as a string replace in all my other df.replace lines. The * is a special character and should have been just df.replace as it's an exact match not a string replace, the regex did not work with that special character.

Comment: you don't need regex here as `*` is a special character, use `df['col'].str.replace('*','')` `regex` is set to False by default in `str.replace`

Comment: That worked! Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to replace it with '' or np.nan ? You can also give None instead of `''`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: replace substring in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38565849/pandas-replace-substring-in-string)

Comment: I believe the issue was passing the regex argument when it wasn't needed. Removing that from the replace seems to have worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'COL_1': ['XYZ', 'XYZ'], 'COL_2': ['*', '123']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
Out[3]: 
  COL_1 COL_2
0   XYZ     *
1   XYZ   123
```

You just need to replace by the str method.

```
df['COL_2'] = df['COL_2'].str.replace('*','')
df
Out[8]: 
  COL_1 COL_2
0   XYZ      
1   XYZ   123
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I am reading on the correct usage of regex vs string replace.